# Error in Python Code. How do I fix a skip?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am really new to coding in general and started Python only recently, and am working on some really beginner practice problems... And I'm working on if and else functions. I followed the tutorial (from yt with exact code) and can't figure out why it won't register correctly.

The practice problem is a simple weight converter from kg to lbs using if and else functions.

```
weight = int(input("Weight: "))
kg_lbs = input("(K)g or (L)bs?")
converted_one = weight / 0.454
converted = weight * 0.45

if kg_lbs.upper == "K":
    print("Weight in lbs: " + str(converted_one))
else:
    print("Weight in kgs: " + str(converted))
```

When k is entered from input, it is meant to print "Weight in lbs: " + str(converted_one)), but it just doesn't register the code and does the else code. And if I remove the else code or replace it w/ something simple such as print("done"), and run it again, it will just continue to skip the if code and do the else code...

The yt video I used for reference is (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kqtD5dpn9C8) at 41:00.

Comment: `.upper` is a function:  `.upper()`. Also, you might want to consider renaming you 'converted' variables to something more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Larry the Llama says in the comment, `upper` is a function, so you need to use it like this:

```
some_string.upper()
```